# 22.10 boot with kernel 5.19.0-31-generic hangs

Tags: boot, kernel

When I try to boot the 5.19.0-31-generic kernel the system hangs after displaying the following lines on the screen

> [    3.179786] hid-generic 0003:1532:024E.0004: No inputs registered,
> leaving [    8.283419] razerkbd 0003:1532:024E.0004: No inputs
> registered, leaving

The same system boots fine using the 5.19.0-29-generic kernel.

Not really sure what to look for but when I look at the boot logs using journalctl for the failed boot there is this line in red lettering

> hid-generic 0003:1532:024E.0004: No inputs registered, leaving

The remaining lines in a the log output from that line are

```
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: razerkbd 0003:1532:024E.0004: No inputs registered, leaving
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0b:00.3/sound/card2/input26
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: razerkbd 0003:1532:024E.0004: hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Razer Razer BlackWidow V3] on usb-0000:02:00.0-5/input3
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: kvm: support for 'kvm_amd' disabled by bios
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:09:00.1/sound/card0/input22
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: razerkbd 0003:1532:024E.0002: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer BlackWidow V3] on usb-0000:02:00.0-5/input1
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0b:00.3/sound/card2/input27
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: input: Razer Razer BlackWidow V3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.4/0003:1532:024E.0005/input/input32
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: kvm: support for 'kvm_amd' disabled by bios
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0b:00.3/sound/card2/input28
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: input: Razer Razer Nostromo as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:0a:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2.3/5-2.3:1.0/0003:1532:0111.0006/input/input33
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: razerkbd 0003:1532:024E.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Razer Razer BlackWidow V3] on usb-0000:02:00.0-5/input4
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0b:00.3/sound/card2/input29
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: kvm: support for 'kvm_amd' disabled by bios
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: razerkbd 0003:1532:0111.0006: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Nostromo] on usb-0000:0a:00.3-2.3/input0
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1676898823.494:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=776 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1676898823.494:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=774 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1676898823.494:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/haveged" pid=780 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1676898823.494:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=767 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1676898823.494:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=768 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1676898823.494:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=768 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1676898823.494:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oosplash" pid=773 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1676898823.494:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=771 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1676898823.494:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=771 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1676898823.494:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=771 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: input: Razer Razer DeathAdder V2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1532:0084.0008/input/input34
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: razermouse 0003:1532:0084.0008: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [Razer Razer DeathAdder V2] on usb-0000:02:00.0-8/input0
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: input: Razer Razer Nostromo as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:0a:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2.3/5-2.3:1.1/0003:1532:0111.0007/input/input35
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: kvm: support for 'kvm_amd' disabled by bios
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: razerkbd 0003:1532:0111.0007: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Razer Razer Nostromo] on usb-0000:0a:00.3-2.3/input1
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: input: Razer Razer DeathAdder V2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.1/0003:1532:0084.0009/input/input36
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: kvm: support for 'kvm_amd' disabled by bios
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: input: Razer Razer DeathAdder V2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.2/0003:1532:0084.000A/input/input37
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: razermouse 0003:1532:0084.0009: input,hidraw8: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [Razer Razer DeathAdder V2] on usb-0000:02:00.0-8/input1
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: razermouse 0003:1532:0084.000B: hiddev1,hidraw9: USB HID v1.11 Device [Razer Razer DeathAdder V2] on usb-0000:02:00.0-8/input3
Feb 20 13:13:43 Freedom kernel: kvm: support for 'kvm_amd' disabled by bios
Feb 20 13:13:44 Freedom kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
Feb 20 13:13:44 Freedom kernel: razermouse 0003:1532:0084.000A: input,hidraw10: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [Razer Razer DeathAdder V2] on usb-0000:02:00.0-8/input2
Feb 20 13:13:44 Freedom kernel: kvm: support for 'kvm_amd' disabled by bios
Feb 20 13:13:47 Freedom kernel: igb 0000:06:00.0 enp6s0: igb: enp6s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
Feb 20 13:13:47 Freedom kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp6s0: link becomes ready
Feb 20 13:14:55 Freedom kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp6s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:18:35:d1:19:cc:e8:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=29603 PROTO=2
```

My system specs are

```
Kubuntu 22.10
Plasma Version: 5.26.5
Frameworks version: 5.102.0
Qt version: 5.15.6
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
```

The system is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a couple of weeks with this issue, got an update today for the 5.19.0-31-generic kernel which has resolved the issue.